# Image reflection effect using pure CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image in `<img>` tag. My aim is to create a reflection of that image using only CSS.
It also has to be compatible with all browsers. I tried various ways to do it one of them is in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/5/)

**What I want:**
The Fade to Zero opacity from top to bottom on the reflection. Right now it works only in webkit browsers using combination of `-webkit-box-reflect` and `-webkit-gradient`.

I want it to work on Mozilla too.

**What I have right now:**
As it can be seen in the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/5/) I got it working in the webkit browsers using:

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px 
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, from(transparent), color-stop(70%, transparent) , to(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1)));
```

I tried the following for Mozilla:

```
#moz-reflect:after {  
    content: "";  
    display: block;  
    background: -moz-element(#moz-reflect) no-repeat;  
    width: auto;  
    height: 200px;  
    margin-bottom: 100px;  
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);  
}
```

where `#moz-reflect` is the container div for the `<img>`.

I'd appreciate answers which can solve the problem with CSS only. There are a lot of images  (Icons) to which this effect has to be applied.

If there is no way it can be made to work in Mozilla using just CSS then I wouldn't mind going down the JavaScript road.

**Update**
It has to work on custom background which may be an image or black or any other color.

Comment: how are you going to do this for IE with pure CSS??

Comment: I'm not concerned with IE at the moment, that'll ofcourse be a bonus ;) my main concern is Mozilla

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've changed your code totally, I am using CSS3 gradients with `transform` property, this is **Pure CSS** with maximum compatibility.

Here, the key thing I am using is `rgba()` along with the `transform` property applied to second `img` which am targeting using `nth-of-type` pseudo.

Also, make sure that you have called `position: relative;` on the parent element because I am using `:after` pseudo for the gradient overlay from the *bottom*, so am using `position: absolute;` for that with the `bottom` set to `0`

<s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/6/)</s> *(Had made a bit **mistake here** by using `rotate()` as it won't give reflection effect, will just rotate the image infact, please refer to my second demonstration)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/8/) *(Using `scale` for mirroring images, can use `rotateY` as well, as pointed out in the comments..)*

```
#moz-reflect:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /*I've removed proprietary gradient codes from here, you can get it in the demo*/
}

#moz-reflect img:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
       -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
         -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
            transform: scaleY(-1); 
}

#moz-reflect {
    position: relative;
}
```

---

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/11/) *(Only difference is, that am using `height: 50%;` for the `:after` pseudo so we don't have to hard code it)*

Only code to modify in the above block of code is the `height` property which am setting to `50%`

```
#moz-reflect:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%; /* Changed the unit over here */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

---

Note: Inorder to create the gradients best suited, say black opaque gradients will be required for websites with black background, than you can make your own using [Color Zilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Image reflection, using `black` as the `body` `background`. Only changes in the above snippet of code is that am applying `background: #000;` to `body` and I've tweaked the gradient accordingly.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/12/) *(For websites using darker backgrounds, black in this case)*

**Note: Didn't added proprietary properties for gradient in the black demo**

Comment: To get the desire effect I suggest use `scaleY` instead of `rotate` Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FWB7K/7/. With rotate seems not fine the effect

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Albeit what you did there will work when there is white background alright, but with custom background it wouldn't look great. I have just updated my question. I forgot to include that part earlier.

Comment: @Danko was editing the answer only, cuz I realized when I was watching the demo, I made this on an image where it wasn't y axis conscious, refreshed 2 to 3 times but didn't striked that the thing was wrong at first place :) though thanks for the comment...

Comment: @FillipPeyton yes we can, I was bit excited while posting, so fixed the codes now, thanks for the inputs.. appreciated...

Comment: @vineetrok well, that's all from me, if you add the conditions lately I cannot help it :) and you welcome.. you can wait for another solutions if this didn't sufficed..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yep, my bad! Your answer will suffice for now. If my updated condition is satisfied it'll be a bonus. So, i'll wait for other answers if they are coming.

Comment: @Charles380 if you have another solution post it - editing content in answers (aside from grammar, broken links, etc) is bad mojo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single image element along with `::before` and `::after`, however it's not very useful (yet), since you have to hard-code a `background-image:url()` for the `::before` pseudo-element. I'm posting this answer because someone else may want to do it this way, and hopefully one day we'll be able to use `background-image: attr(src, url);` syntax. (1) As of June 2014, no browsers support this.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeedH/5/

I'm assuming you have a black background.

Structure:

1. `img` - main image (actually displayed as a background-image),
2. `::before` containing the reflection. Must be `display:inline-block` in order to use the `transform:scaleY` to flip the image.
3. `::after` containing a gradient mask.

The html: (note that currently the `src` is not used).

```
<img class="reflect" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYXWxD2yC7m2m1ZylyVq_r6yWE4ewJv64cmt3CpgbGdqZq3wEx" />
```

The CSS:

```
.reflect {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYXWxD2yC7m2m1ZylyVq_r6yWE4ewJv64cmt3CpgbGdqZq3wEx');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    content:'';
}
.reflect::before {
    position:relative;
    top:20%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-.7);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-.7);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-.7);
    transform:scaleY(-.7);
    opacity:0.2;
    background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYXWxD2yC7m2m1ZylyVq_r6yWE4ewJv64cmt3CpgbGdqZq3wEx');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    content:'';
}
.reflect::after {
    position:relative;
    top:-40%;
    height:70%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(top center, 50% 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    background-image:-moz-radial-gradient(top center, 50% 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    background-image:-o-radial-gradient(top center, 50% 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    background-image:radial-gradient(top center, 50% 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    content:'';
}
```

Note that you must use `content:'';` on the `img` itself, otherwise the pseudo-elements won't display.

Also be aware that this is not really applicable to a class of images because you have to hard-code the image url. But this could be useful if you used it by id and used js to write the rules to a document level stylesheet.  Otherwise, this is only helpful for single images.

(1). [Using HTML data-attribute to set CSS background-image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734546/using-html-data-attribute-to-set-css-background-image-url)