# HTML passing image URL variable to CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML template with image blocks. Those images are loaded via CSS using background-image. Now the problem is that I can't pass these variables from my PHP code into CSS. The only solutions I manage to think of is to use inline HTML style attribute with background-image link, or just leave the image link as a data attribute in HTML and put the background-image css using JavaScript. Any other ideas?

[Using HTML data-attribute to set CSS background-image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734546/using-html-data-attribute-to-set-css-background-image-url)

Comment: You allready named all the possibilities. Inline `CSS`, `data-*` or `JavaScript`. Just choose yourself. Because the awnser(s) will mostly be opinion based. And thats not a awnser that belongs on SO.

Comment: Inline css is the best solution. (for me)

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to check if there is another way. Hope the attribute passing to CSS will work someday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind inline styles I can recommend using inline `background-image` anyway. Personally I've never run into problem when I need to update this value and this way seems to be clear and easy if you forEach some elements.

Also the big advantage by using this method is you control **content** with html/php and **styling** with actual css, so it might be even better to do it this way instead of passing it to css.

```
<img class="..." style=background-image: url("<?= $img ?>");>
```

If you are lazy-loading with javascript, this is as simple as reverting `style` into some `data-attribute` like `data-bg`