# Backend: Is it possible to fetch image locatiom in css background(url) from database?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I've thrown my data to my blade. I'm using inline css. In this case, I need `background: url(..)` instead of `<img>`. On browser when i inspect and open the img in new file it opens but css is unable to parse and display it. Should i give it some more location?

Currently, I'm trying this out.

```
<div class="row profile-cover" style="margin: 0; 
background: url('{{$userDetails->profile_img}}')">
```

where

```
$userDetails->profile_img= gallery/client4/avatar_1530513317_1532258485.jpg;
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734546/using-html-data-attribute-to-set-css-background-image-url

Answer (score 0):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
<div class="row profile-cover" style="margin: 0; background: url({{ asset($userDetails->profile_img) }})">
```

Or

```
<div class="row profile-cover" style="margin: 0; background-image: url({{ asset($userDetails->profile_img) }})">
```

Comment: when i add assets .. i get background: url(http://localhost:800') only .. i dont get my path why?

Comment: @ReyYoung Check if your image and image field in database is empty or not